# Express.js displaying the req.body undefined with routes regroup from other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a beginner in using Node.js Express framework. I followed a tutorial and experimenting routes from Express framework. I am trying to prepare for API call and regroup my routes. I have a structure like this in index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const dishRouter = require('./routes/dishRouter');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const app = express();

app.use('/dishes', dishRouter);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}`);
});
```

I was regrouping my routes from a different file and I have a problem regarding on accepting `req.body.name` and `req.body.description` in the code below dishRouter.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const dishRouter = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

dishRouter.route('/')
.all((req,res,next) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    next();
})
.get((req,res,next) => {
    res.end('Will send all the dishes to you!');
})
.post((req, res, next) => {
    res.end('Will add the dish: ' + req.body.name + ' with details: ' + req.body.description);
})
.put((req, res, next) => {
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.end('PUT operation not supported on /dishes');
})
.delete((req, res, next) => {
    res.end('Deleting all dishes');
});

dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
dishRouter.route('/:dishId')
.get((req, res, next) => {
    res.end('Will send the dish id: ' + req.params.dishId + ' to you!');
})
.put((req, res, next) => {
    res.write('Updating the dish: ' + req.params.dishId + '\n');
    res.end('Will update the dish: ' + req.body.name + 
        ' with details: ' + req.body.description);
});

module.exports = dishRouter;
```

Here I have separated my routes but when I tried in Postman, `req.body.name` and the `req.body.description`, it gives me undefined value.

How can i get the values from this?

Comment: I would simple place `bodyParser.json()` to the index.js `app.use(bodyParser.json())` and it will work for every route.

Comment: @Molda why still undefined?
Updating the dish: 1
Will update the dish: undefined with details: undefined

Comment: @Molda here i tried like this : 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/dishes', dishRouter);

Comment: Is the data you are sending to the server actualy a JSON? How do you send the data from client?

Comment: @Molda oh god!. sorry. I already fixed it. thanks. Forgot to change the text to JSON in postman

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to put `dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());` before `dishRouter.route('/')` so the middleware runs first then only go to the route.

**UPDATE**

Checkout this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-wind-vdylp)

You can try by using `curl` to test the endpoint:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/dishes' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "new dish",
    "description": "new dish description"
}'
```

Or try in your local environment using Postman.

Hope it helps :D

Comment: dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
dishRouter.route('/')
I tried like this but still undefined in postman

Comment: It's working for me, check out this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-wind-vdylp) P.S. Express comes with `body-parser` now so you don't need to add separate dependency